# Adding a Xamarin Form to Xamarin iOS unified app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin iOS unified app.
I want to add a Xamarin form to it.
How can I do this?

Thanks,
Kaustubh

Answer (score 1):

-You can not do it directly.

-Create a Xamarin PCL project, it will create a shared project and native projects to iOS and Android

-You can add you Xamarin native project, necessary files to it

-Create a page renderer in Xamarin Forms Shared project

-Use it  to load required page from native project

-Page renderer will act as a native page.You can call your native functions, UI from that point onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin forms is a kind of project, not a form you can add to a project that is not xamarin forms

You can just add a new project of type Xamarin.Forms in your solution and you'll then have to port your code or share as much as possible through a PCL.

Source and reference : developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/

[Edited to take comments into accounts]

Comment: I have a Xamarin iOS app, in which I need to add a xamarin form on some action.

Comment: Ok so that might be the documentation you're looking for : http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/ first steps show you how to create/add a xamarin.forms project to a solution.